# Add info to output -- obtained from a shell command execution

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cmd, getline

I have files containing indented lines such as:

```
table 't'
  field 'abc'
  field 'def' and @enabled=true
  field 'ghi'
table 'u'
```

I want to transform it to:

```
table 't'
  field 'abc' [info about ABC]
  field 'def' [info about DEF] and @enabled=true
  field 'ghi' [info about GHI]
table 'u'
```

where the string between brackets is get from the call of a shell script (`get-info`, that fetches the definition of terms 'abc', 'def' and 'ghi').

I tried with AWK (via the `cmd | getline output` mechanism):

```
awk '$1 == "field" {
    $2 = substr($2, 2, length($2) - 2)
    cmd = "get-info \"" $2 "\" 2>&1 | head -n 1" # results or error
    while (cmd | getline output) {
        print $0 " [" output "]";
    }
    close(cmd)
    next
}
// { print $0 }'
```

but it does not respect the indentation!

How could I fulfil my wish?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Perhaps adding your Awk script would help clarify where you are stuck.

Comment: I've tried to express my request more clearly. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you're trying to do would be:

```
$1 == "field" {
    cmd = "get-info \"" substr($2,2,length($2)-2) "\" 2>&1" # results or error
    if ( (cmd | getline output) > 0 ) {
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+/,"& ["output"]")
    }
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }
```

Note you don't need the `head -1`, just don't read the output in a loop.

e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 == "field" {
    cmd = "echo \"--->" substr($2,2,length($2)-2) "<---\" 2>&1"
    if ( (cmd | getline output) > 0 ) {
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+/,"& ["output"]")
    }
    close(cmd)
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
table 't'
  field 'abc'
  field 'def' [--->def<---] and @enabled=true
  field 'ghi'
table 'u'
```

This is a rare occasion where use of `getline` is probably appropriate but make sure you read and understand all of the `getline` caveats at http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're considering using `getline` again.

Comment: What can I say other than "perfect!"?  And thanks a lot for the added note over `head -1`...